# Options can be selected from php

Tags: php, switch-statement

I working on a PHP project and so far it looks like its supposed to:
[image]
The site is supposed to give the actual size of the lumber that they have selected
[image]
My problem is that no matter what they select I get either `3/4" x 1-1/2"` if they click on inches or `19 x 38 mm` if they click on metrics.
I'm familiar with a little coding but I am not the best at it and would appreciate as much help as I can get.
**This is the code for my input page which is HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en" style="text-align:center; zoom:150%;">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> Final - Lumber</title>
  </head>

  <body style="background-color: lightgrey;">
    <h1 style="color:white; background-color:black;">
      <?php
        //Includes the code to connect to the server
        //include_once 'includes/dbc.php';
      ?>
    </h1>
    <p> Please complete this form to submit your input: </p>

    <p><span style="color:#FF0000">* required filed</span></p>
    <form method="post" action="handler.php">
      <p>
        <label> What size of lumber would you want?
          <select name="size" required>
            <option value="NULL" disabled selected> -------- </option>
            <option value="1"> 1" X 2" </option>
            <option value="2"> 1" X 3" </option>
            <option value="3"> 1" X 4" </option>
            <option value="4"> 1" X 5" </option>
            <option value="5"> 1" X 6" </option>
            <option value="6"> 1" X 7" </option>
            <option value="7"> 1" X 8" </option>
            <option value="8"> 1" X 10" </option>
            <option value="9"> 1" X 12" </option>
            <option value="10"> 2" X 4" </option>
            <option value="11"> 2" X 6" </option>
            <option value="12"> 2" X 8" </option>
            <option value="13"> 2" X 10" </option>
            <option value="14"> 2" X 12" </option>
            <option value="15"> 3" X 6" </option>
            <option value="16"> 4" X 4" </option>
            <option value="17"> 4" X 6" </option>
          </select>
        </label>
          <span style="color:#FF0000">*</span>
      </p>

      <p>
        <label> Choose how you would like the actual sizes displayed?
        </label>
          <span style="color:#FF0000">*</span>
      </p>

      <input type="submit" name="inches" value="Inches">
      <input type="submit" name="metric" value="Metric">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

**And this is my handler.php code which is suppose to provide the right size for the lumber they selected**

```
<?php
      //connects to the server
      //include_once 'includes/dbc.php';

      //Renaming values to make it easier to write
      $size = isset($_POST['size']);
      $metric = isset($_POST['metric']);
      $inches = isset($_POST['inches']);

      //If they click on the inches button
      if ($inches)
      {
        switch ($size) {
          case '$_POST["1"]':
            echo 'The actual size of a 1" x 2"<br><br>';
            echo '<span style="color:blue;">3/4" x 1-1/2"</span<br/>';
            break;
          case '$_POST["2"]':
            echo 'The actual size of a 1" x 3"<br><br>';
            echo '<span style="color:blue;">3/4” x 2-1/2”</span<br/>';
            break;
          case '3':
            echo 'The actual size of a 1" x 4"<br><br>';
            echo '<span style="color:blue;">3/4” x 3-1/2”</span<br/>';
            break;
          case '4':
            echo 'The actual size of a 1" x 5"<br><br>';
            echo '<span style="color:blue;">3/4” x 4-1/2”</span<br/>';
            break;
          case '5':
            echo 'The actual size of a 1" x 6"<br><br>';
            echo '<span style="color:blue;">3/4” x 5-1/2”</span<br/>';
            break;
          case '6':
            echo 'The actual size of a 1" x 7"<br><br>';
            echo '<span style="color:blue;">3/4” x 6-1/4”</span<br/>';
            break;
          case '7':
            echo 'The actual size of a 1" x 8"<br><br>';
            echo '<span style="color:blue;">3/4” x 7-1/4”</span<br/>';
            break;
          case '8':
            echo 'The actual size of a 1" x 10"<br><br>';
            echo '<span style="color:blue;">3/4” x 9-1/4”</span<br/>';
            break;
          case '9':
            echo 'The actual size of a 1" x 12"<br><br>';
            echo '<span style="color:blue;">3/4” x 11-1/4”</span<br/>';
            break;
          case '10':
            echo 'The actual size of a 2" x 4"<br><br>';
            echo '<span style="color:blue;">1-1/2” x 3-1/2”</span<br/>';
            break;
          case '11':
            echo 'The actual size of a 2" x 6"<br><br>';
            echo '<span style="color:blue;">1-1/2” x 5-1/2”</span<br/>';
            break;
          case '12':
            echo 'The actual size of a 2" x 8"<br><br>';
            echo '<span style="color:blue;">1-1/2” x 7-1/4”</span<br/>';
            break;
          case '13':
            echo 'The actual size of a 2" x 10"<br><br>';
            echo '<span style="color:blue;">1-1/2” x 9-1/4”</span<br/>';
            break;
          case '14':
            echo 'The actual size of a 2" x 12"<br><br>';
            echo '<span style="color:blue;">1-1/2” x 11-1/4”</span<br/>';
            break;
          case '15':
            echo 'The actual size of a 3" x 6"<br><br>';
            echo '<span style="color:blue;">2-1/2” x 5-1/2” </span<br/>';
            break;
          case '16':
            echo 'The actual size of a 4" x 4"<br><br>';
            echo '<span style="color:blue;">3-1/2” x 3-1/2” </span<br/>';
            break;
          case '17':
            echo 'The actual size of a 4" x 6"<br><br>';
            echo '<span style="color:blue;">3-1/2” x 5-1/2” </span<br/>';
            break;
          }

      }
      elseif ($metric) {
        switch ($size) {
          case '$_POST["1"]':
            echo 'The actual size of a 1" x 2"<br><br>';
            echo '<span style="color:blue;">19 x 38 mm</span<br/>';
            break;
          case '$_POST["2"]':
            echo 'The actual size of a 1" x 3"<br><br>';
            echo '<span style="color:blue;">3/4” x 2-1/2”</span<br/>';
            break;
          case '3':
            echo 'The actual size of a 1" x 4"<br><br>';
            echo '<span style="color:blue;">3/4” x 3-1/2”</span<br/>';
            break;
          case '4':
            echo 'The actual size of a 1" x 5"<br><br>';
            echo '<span style="color:blue;">3/4” x 4-1/2”</span<br/>';
            break;
          case '5':
            echo 'The actual size of a 1" x 6"<br><br>';
            echo '<span style="color:blue;">3/4” x 5-1/2”</span<br/>';
            break;
          case '6':
            echo 'The actual size of a 1" x 7"<br><br>';
            echo '<span style="color:blue;">3/4” x 6-1/4”</span<br/>';
            break;
          case '7':
            echo 'The actual size of a 1" x 8"<br><br>';
            echo '<span style="color:blue;">3/4” x 7-1/4”</span<br/>';
            break;
          case '8':
            echo 'The actual size of a 1" x 10"<br><br>';
            echo '<span style="color:blue;">3/4” x 9-1/4”</span<br/>';
            break;
          case '9':
            echo 'The actual size of a 1" x 12"<br><br>';
            echo '<span style="color:blue;">3/4” x 11-1/4”</span<br/>';
            break;
          case '10':
            echo 'The actual size of a 2" x 4"<br><br>';
            echo '<span style="color:blue;">1-1/2” x 3-1/2”</span<br/>';
            break;
          case '11':
            echo 'The actual size of a 2" x 6"<br><br>';
            echo '<span style="color:blue;">1-1/2” x 5-1/2”</span<br/>';
            break;
          case '12':
            echo 'The actual size of a 2" x 8"<br><br>';
            echo '<span style="color:blue;">1-1/2” x 7-1/4”</span<br/>';
            break;
          case '13':
            echo 'The actual size of a 2" x 10"<br><br>';
            echo '<span style="color:blue;">1-1/2” x 9-1/4”</span<br/>';
            break;
          case '14':
            echo 'The actual size of a 2" x 12"<br><br>';
            echo '<span style="color:blue;">1-1/2” x 11-1/4”</span<br/>';
            break;
          case '15':
            echo 'The actual size of a 3" x 6"<br><br>';
            echo '<span style="color:blue;">2-1/2” x 5-1/2” </span<br/>';
            break;
          case '16':
            echo 'The actual size of a 4" x 4"<br><br>';
            echo '<span style="color:blue;">3-1/2” x 3-1/2” </span<br/>';
            break;
          case '17':
            echo 'The actual size of a 4" x 6"<br><br>';
            echo '<span style="color:blue;">3-1/2” x 5-1/2” </span<br/>';
            break;
        }
      }


     ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My stab at this is you're turning your `$size` variable into a boolean.

```
$size = (isset($_POST['size'])) ? $_POST['size'] : 0; //<-Whatever value you want if it's not set
```